# Can I use custom lowercase chord names with 'songs' package while using `\transpose` feature?

Tags: songs

I'm writing a songbook with the (quite good!) `songs` package. I want to leverage its transposition ability, but I noticed something from [the manual](https://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec7): if I want to use the solfedge note names (i.e. the latin ones, Do - Re - Mi etc.), I must use them in **capital** letters, which is tedious. I can still compose the document with lowercase notes using the ~\notenamesin`/`\notenamesout` macros, but I wondered: **is there a workaround?** Should I open a feature or pull request?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, the current behaviour gives three possibilities:

- Normal setting: only alphabetical names

```latex
\[G]How many \[C]roads must a \[D]man walk \[G]down,
before you \[C]call him a \[G]man
```

- Using the `\solfedge` macro, but the chords must be provided in capitals to allow transposition

```latex
\solfedge
[...]
\[SOL]How many \[DO]roads must a \[RE]man walk \[SOL]down,
before you \[DO]call him a \[SOL]man
```

Notice this also produces the chords in capitals.

I'd like instead:

```latex
\somecommands
[...]
\[Sol]How many \[Do]roads must a \[Re]man walk \[Sol]down,
before you \[Do]call him a \[Sol]man
```

but this doesn't get recognized by the transpose engine.

The current partial solution I found is:

```latex
\notenamesin{LA}{SI}{DO}{RE}{MI}{FA}{SOL}
\notenamesout{La}{Si}{Do}{Re}{Mi}{Fa}{Sol}
[...]
\[SOL]How many \[DO]roads must a \[RE]man walk \[SOL]down,
before you \[DO]call him a \[SOL]man
```

this way I still have to type in the chords in capitals, but they get composed with only the initial capital and they get correctly transposed. The point is that the chords needs to be (IIUC) in capitals so the package can distinguish them from accents (flats, sharps, minors, sevenths etc.).

Comment: Possibly, but it would require digging through the songs source code.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? Currently I don't fully understand what kind of input you want to provide and what kind of output you expect from that, or why `\notenamesin` and `\notenamesout` is not a solution for this. Could you provide a full document example with the code that you would like to use?

Comment: I edit the title to highlight the issue is with the `\transpose` feature, because otherwise the package does work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A "without thinking" way is to patching/pile up on the original definition of `\[` (whatever it is) to replace the definition whenever it's in a lookup table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aless_patched_value_Sol: { \__aless_old_open_bracket:w SOL] }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aless_patched_value_Do:  { \__aless_old_open_bracket:w DO]  }
% type the rest yourself

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aless_patched_open_bracket:w #1 ] {
    \cs_if_exist_use:cF {__aless_patched_value_ #1 :} {  % unlike e-TeX's \ifdefined this also returns true when the control sequence has meaning \relax
        \__aless_old_open_bracket:w #1 ]
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \custompatch {
    \let \__aless_old_open_bracket:w \[
    \let \[ \__aless_patched_open_bracket:w
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{}

\solfedge
\notenamesout{La}{Si}{Do}{Re}{Mi}{Fa}{Sol}

\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
sr={Revelation 5:13},
cr={Public domain.}]
\beginverse

\transpose{1}

\custompatch  % ← run this command here

\[Sol]How many \[Do]roads 

\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Control sequence names "roughly" follow expl3 naming convention, with OP username used as the module name.

(note this may file with certain definitions of robust commands where `\[` itself is called internally in the source code of the package. Nevertheless it mostly works.)

Answer (score 1):

Define `\Sol` macro which redefines `\[` and re-define `\beginverse` in order it applies `\Sol`

```
\def\Sol {\let\solori=\[ \def\[##1]{\uppercase{\solori##1]}}}
\expandafter\def \expandafter\beginverse \expandafter{\beginverse\Sol}
```